# Dynamic Excel dropboxes? (with selected values from other table)

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Please I need help implementing multiple dynamic dropboxes in Excel:

- On sheet 1 there is a filled table
- On sheet 2 there is an empty table with the same column headers
- On sheet 2 the table is filled by the user with the exception of the last column
- On sheet 2 in the last column there should be **a dropbox in each row. This dropbox must contain a selection of values from the same column in table 1. The selection should consider only rows in table 1 matching fields already filled in the table 2 row where the dropbox resides**. See example below.

The whole thing should require no additional user interaction and should also allow inserting arbitrary values in addition to those of the dropbox.

---

### Example

TABLE 1

BRAND | CPU | MODEL
brand1 | cpu1 | modelX
brand1 | cpu1 | modelY
brand1 | cpu2 | modelZ
brand2 | cpu2 | modelH
brand2 | cpu2 | modelK

TABLE 2

BRAND | CPU | MODEL
brand1 | cpu1 | [DROPBOX1]
brand2 | cpu2 | [DROPBOX2]

EXPLANATION

[DROPBOX1] should contain modelX and modelY
[DROPBOX2] should contian modelH and modelK

---

I managed to create **one** such dropbox through a named range within a dedcated table, but that's it. I cannot employ the same system for an arbitrary number of rows.
*The whole thing screams Access, but implementation details came from above so Excel it is (thank you management).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the privilege of receiving support on Microsoft forums from the first EU MVP, Mr. [Bill Manville](http://www.manville.org.uk).
This is the macro which solved the problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim iCol as Integer
  Dim rTable1 As Range
  If Target.Cells.Count<>1 Then Exit Sub
  Set rTable1=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  With Me.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If Target.Column<>.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub
    rTable1.AutoFilter
    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count-1
       rTable1.AutoFilter iCol, Me.Cells(Target.Row, iCol)
    Next
    If rTable1.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count>1 Then
      rTable1.Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(1).Resize(rTable1.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Name = "ValidationList"
    Else
      MsgBox "The combination in this row is not matched"
    End If
    rTable1.AutoFilter
  End With
End Sub
```

He was also so kind as to provide a [working example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18521442/ValidationListDependsOnPreviousEntries.xls)
For these to work **the source table must be ordered**, as data validation would only consider the first section of a named range split in multiple sections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following you, but it appears that a quick setup for this to toy with would be with data Validation on the Data Tab.

1. Select Data Validation from Data Tab
2. Select Data Validation
3. Select from Allow: "List"
4. Under source, there are 2 ways to proceed...
      you can highlight the column range you would like to see on the droplist.
      You can highlight the column range, on the top left where the Column/Row name is, highlight and rename, and use that name as the source.

   I will typically create an additional tab, hide/protect it, then create my drop down sheets from there.

Comment: Thanks for your time, unfortunately this is not sufficient: from that range I need to extract only a selection of results, depending on the values input by the user near the dropbox.